# Excel Formula about returning TRUE and FALSE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making an internet manager using excel formulas, got problems about hours and minutes formulas. Can you please help me with TOTAL FEE ?.

NOTE: 5-30 mins = $5 and 1 hour = $10

My Formula for TOTAL FEE "=IF(OR(F3=5, F3>=30), 5, (3*H3)+(E3*60+F3)/60*G3)"

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Click the link for the picture, thanks !

Comment: Can you give some worked examples to show what you want as the output. Eg If I work (0 hours, 40 minutes) or (1 hour , 7 minutes) or (5 hours, 45 minutes)

Comment: @RobAnthony 5-30 Mins = $5, every 1 min additional gains $0.17 and 1 hour = $10 Thank you

Comment: What do you pay if a person works for 1 hour and 3 minutes?

Comment: The logic of your form is wrong. The charge isn't $10 per hour. Instead it is $5 per half-hour or part thereof. If you wish to give the first 5 minutes for free, or perhaps the first five minutes of ever half-hour, that is another question. Based on this logic you display of "1 hour and 59 minutes" is confusing because it will never show how the charge was calculated. I suggest to show "Actual time used" in minutes and "Chargeable time" in hours, rounded to half-hours.

Comment: @Variatus sorry for the question just new here in stack overflow community im still learning about excel formulas :) Im into Web development but thanks bdw

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
TOTAL FEE "=IF(AND(F3>=5, F3<=30), 5, (3*H3)+(E3*60+F3)/60*G3)"
```

However, you still should edit your question as mentioned in comments.

If you want to charge for printing services no matter the duration, check this:

```
TOTAL FEE "=IF(AND(F3>=5, F3<=30), 5, (E3*60+F3)/60*G3)+(3*H3)"
```

Comment: @JosephAngelo You're welcome. Check also the second solution in case you want to charge for printing services no matter how long did person work.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. @Egan Wolf ! Very much appreciated, Im just learning and familiarizing the excel formulas bdw :( . Im into web development :)

Comment: ! There's a problem in your formula :(

Comment: There's a problem for AM and PM clock rate, it wont change amount regarding the PM  time

Comment: My formula is working on columns E-H, which are filled by your formulas working on columns B-C. I guess the problem is in your formulas not giving right data to columns E-H. Please, edit your question and add this case. For now, I have no idea what is wrong, because you didn't give any details.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
=IF(AND(F3>=5,F3<=30),5,F3*G3/60)+(G3*E3)
```

This checks to see if the number of minutes is between 5 and 30 and, if so, pays $5, if not, it calculates the proportion of the hourly rate from the number of minutes.

Then is adds on the pay for the number of hours worked.

However, this doesn't work properly for minutes from 1-4 it will need to be modified to take this into account.

Comment: I haven't taken into account the payment for printing services (3*H3) in your original formula as this wasn't mentioned in the text. If you need this, just add it on to the end of the formula.

Comment: If this has solved your question, please can you remember to mark it as a correct solution? Thanks.